# Strange complex phase displayed

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Using the following code:

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

Radius=10
N=1024
dx=2*Radius/N
dy=dx
x=r_[-Radius:Radius:dx]
y=r_[-Radius:Radius:dy]
X, Y = meshgrid(x,y)
R = sqrt(X**2+Y**2)
PHI = arctan2(Y,X)

ringthing = R < Radius
ring = zeros((2,N,N),dtype=complex)
ring[0] = ringthing
ring[1] = ringthing*exp(1j*PHI)

f=fig()
p1=f.add_subplot(121)
p1.imshow(angle(ring[0]))
p2=f.add_subplot(122)
p2.imshow(angle(ring[1]))

f.show()
```

The lower left square of the second image is colored red (phase equals pi) for no obvious reason. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the value outside of the circle is zero and the complex angle of zero is not well defined (its a singularity). The float point arithmetics work out such that in some parts they evaluate to `0` and in others to `-0` which is seen by running

```
from __future__ import division

from numpy import *

Radius=10
N=1024
dx=2*Radius/N
dy=dx
x=r_[-Radius:Radius:dx]
y=r_[-Radius:Radius:dy]
X, Y = meshgrid(x,y)
R = sqrt(X**2+Y**2)
PHI = arctan2(Y,X)

ringthing = R < Radius
ring = zeros((2,N,N),dtype=complex)
ring[0] = ringthing
ring[1] = ringthing*exp(1j*PHI)

print ring[1][-1, 0], angle(ring[1][-1, 0])
print ring[1][0, -1], angle(ring[1][0, -1])
```

with the output

```
(-0+0j) 3.14159265359
0j 0.0
```

One solution around this would be to set all values outside the circle to zero explicitly.

Comment: Neat! I was trying to get here, using unwrap() but yes seems like the zero() +/- issue.

Comment: I would argue that it might be useful to have `angle()` return `nan` when given a zero input, but that's basically a definition.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'm considering submitting a bug report for this though. For one, Matlab handles this gracefully, and the pi phase shift is arbitrary as per this example (with some underlying implementation reason as explained in your answer).

Comment: Well the problem is that you ask for the angle of a vanishing complex number, which is not defined. I think the proper implementation should return `nan` or throw an exception, but someone chose to return either 0 or pi depending on the sign. It's an implementation detail, but I would rather change your code, because I don't believe the definition of `angle` is going to be changed.